# Can a singe Dropbox'ed 1Password db be shared between 1Password v4 & v3?

Tags: password

I share my 1Password db on Dropbox across a number of machines.  If I upgrade some machines to 1Password 4, will the 1Password db no longer work with 1Password 3 instances.  Caveat: One of the machines can no longer support OS upgrade beyond Lion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [How do I use 1Password 4 in Snow Leopard or Lion?](http://learn2.agilebits.com/1Password4/Mac/en/KB/legacy-osx.html):

> 1Password 4 for Mac requires Mountain Lion or later.
>
> If you are still rocking an older Mac, we’ve got you covered. We know that you store your most important information in 1Password — we do too! — so we made sure you could still use 1Password 3 for Mac on your older Macs if you need to. 1Password 4 for Mac can sync its data with 1Password 3 for Mac using Dropbox so there’s no issue using both. Access all your data, even on Macs that cannot be upgraded to Mountain Lion. Rock on!

Comment: Thank YOU! [AgileBits](https://agilebits.com/) just wins. Ever consider buying up the The Leafs?